# Debugging Swift Package Manager dependances

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

How do you debug package dependancies you have imported into your project? I can't seem to see the code within the packages.

Currently I am using Carthage and you can simply set breakpoints within the code (there are flags that allow you to do this in Carthage).[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you can use [editable packages](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift_packages/editing_a_package_dependency_as_a_local_package). Not sure how debugging this works though.

Comment: It becomes debuggable by default